# Existe algum comando no sql server que retorna o numero de registros de uma tabela?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, tabela-html

Possuo uma tabela chamada cliente com vários clientes já cadastrados e quero filtrar todos os clientes que tenham a mesma idade e obter um numero inteiro desses registros, no caso a **quantidade** de clientes com a mesma idade.

Comment: Eu nao sei como esta a sua tabela, mas acredito que você possa usar o COUNT na sua consulta.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Precisa definir melhor o problema, a descrição está ambígua. Oque é ter a mesma idade? Comparado a que? Dependendo da descrição todos clientes tem a mesma idade de outro cliente a não ser que ele seja o único com aquela idade, o que é raro acontecer em bases com um tamanho até pequeno, e mesmo que dê uma pequena diferença deve ser irrelevante.

Comment: E você tem o que cadastrado em sua tabela a idade ou a data de nascimento? Caso seja a data de nascimento você quer comparar com a data corrente e qual a precisão que gostaria de utilizar para comparar a igualdade de idade, anos? anos/meses? anos/meses/dias? Se você deseja contar os clientes com a mesma idade então o resultado desta contagem certamente será um número inteiro.

Comment: @RaquelAndrade Obrigado, seu comentário me ajudou bastante. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estou considerando que você tem uma tabela chamada `Cliente`, e nessa tabela tem um campo chamado `DataNasc`.

O código abaixo retorna uma lista de todas as idades e a quantidade de registros com aquela idade:

```
declare @hoje as datetime = getdate()

select idade, count(*) as qtd_idade
from (
    select CASE WHEN datepart(mm,DataNasc) > datepart(mm,@hoje) OR 
                      (datepart(mm,DataNasc) = datepart(mm,@hoje) 
                   AND datepart(dd,DataNasc) >= datepart(dd,@hoje))
                THEN DATEDIFF(year, DataNasc, @hoje) - 1
                ELSE DATEDIFF(year, DataNasc, @hoje)
            end as idade
    from Cliente
) as t
group by idade
```

Me avise se eu tiver entendido errado.